# Sim change alert on galaxy s8?

Tags: samsung, security, sim-card, anti-theft

How do i enable sms alert for sim change on my samsung galaxy s8?

I recently jumped from galaxy s3 to s8.

S3 had this neat feature called "SIM change alert" where you can enter a few phone numbers and if someone unauthorized replaces the sim card then the phone will send sms messages to the phone numbers entered earlier alerting them about the theft and thrives phone number.

However I'm unable to find a similar feature in my galaxy s8. Some articles on the internet state that signing in on my google account automatically activates antitheft features. But i don't see a place to enter phone no where alert messages would be sent

Running android 7.0

Answer (score 2):

I had Same concern, got response fro Samsung itself, it seems they have discontinued "SIM Change Alert" after Nougat update. They have suggested to use third party app as an option,

Find below screenshot of chat for your reference:

[image: IMG:]